# Converting a PDF file to Excel file using SautinSoft reference shows no error but no Excel output files either

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

I have used the code from this [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Convert-PDF-file-to-Excel-f20be75e#content) to convert PDF to Excel file. No error is observed in Visual Studio but no output file in Excel format was found either. Hoping for feedback. Please note that I'm new in C#.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string pathToPdf = @"C:\cSharp\PDFToExcelConversion\IT.pdf";
    string pathToExcel = @"C:\cSharp\PDFToExcelConversion\excelconverted.xls";

    // Convert PDF file to Excel file 
    SautinSoft.PdfFocus f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus();

    // 'true' = Convert all data to spreadsheet (tabular and even textual). 
    // 'false' = Skip textual data and convert only tabular (tables) data. 
    f.ExcelOptions.ConvertNonTabularDataToSpreadsheet = true;

    // 'true'  = Preserve original page layout. 
    // 'false' = Place tables before text. 
    f.ExcelOptions.PreservePageLayout = true;

    f.OpenPdf(pathToPdf);

    if (f.PageCount > 0)
    {
        int result = f.ToExcel(pathToExcel);

        //Open a produced Excel workbook 
        if (result == 0)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathToExcel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know SautinSoft, but from what you describe, it sounds likely that `f.PageCount` is 0.  I would suggest debugging your program and looking at the properties of `f` after you execute `OpenPdf(pathToPdf)`.

Comment: Thanks Ann for your feedback. The Excel file output appeared on my second attempt of running the program and it took about 15/20 minutes before Excel file was found in the output location. I will check the suggestion you have made that will help me understand the code a bit more. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It took about sometime before the Excel file was found in the output folder. Because the PDF was relatively large, I think that was the reason the code wasn't producing the Excel file quickly enough. Also, I have used a trial version of the library, so only 3 pages of PDF can be converted at a time. Hoping this code helps someone.